# Автосохранение текста

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтоб textbox автоматически сохранялся, к примеру через 1 минуту?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Создать [таймер](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=VS.100).aspx) на 1 минуту и в его обработчике сохранять содержимое textbox

Answer (score 2):

Самый примитивный способ - через Timer. В обработчике события Tick сохраняете свой текстбокс, а в свойстве Interval выставляете время.